# Local development server risk: inbound connection

Tags: windows, security, firewall, hacking, xampp

My local development environment is Windows with xampp/nginx. Yesterday I installed malwarebytes and today when I started my xampp server, I soon find out that there is an inbound connection blocked by malwarebytes trying to access from port 443, the ip address comes from Czech which I have zero assocation to.

I am kind of worried now as I have been using the same local server config for some time, hence previous inbound attempts might not have been blocked.

Is this situation risky at all? Am I missing some must have security measures that make me vulnerable to hackers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is port 443 normally open from external?  If it is, then it would be normal to see random traffic like this.

Now, if you have this server "out on the internet" with no firewall and this server has been accessible from the outside this whole time on various ports, and you haven't locked down any security, etc. then yeah you should be concerned (but the server should have been compromised by now to be honest).

If this server is going to be accessible from external, then look at locking down to the ports required, setting up the proper user security, etc.  That's not something that is universal though, each configuration is a little different depending on need.

Knowledge links:

http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-security-hardening

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/Install-XAMPP-on-Windows/1/

http://bobstrand.com/totm/2010/01/securing-your-xampp/